# Parallel connect 2 batteries while the panels are separate?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, parallel

I have 2 solar panels, 100w and 125w. They will separately power one 100ah battery each. Can I parallel connect the 2 batteries for charging purposes or should the batteries separately go to the same 30amp charge controller to then charge my stuff? This is a 12v system.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would connect the two batteries in parallel to the controller and the two panels in parallel to the controller.

Separating each panel / battery would need a second controller - then you may consider a method of supplying the loads from either battery with a changeover for backup.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't connecting the two panels that don't have the same wattage cause me to lose some of that wattage?

Comment: Either use diodes or put the panels in series if the charge controller can handle the input.

Comment: The panels in parallel won't "loose" the difference in power, it will all go into the charge controller. But blocking diodes may still be a good idea.